# struts 1 action class with instance variable

Tags: java, servlets, struts, action

Please find below code in my project:

```
public class MyAction extends Action 
{
   RefList refList = null;

   public ActionForward execute(...) 
   {
      refList = (RefList) getServlet().getServletContext().getAttribute("refList");
   }
}
```

All users read data from servlet context and initialize refList instance variable in execute method. (Please check above code)
Only one admin user can refresh or write into servlet context attribute when he insert or update data into some dimension tables.

Now problem is when admin user refresh servlet context data, sometime(very rare) some users doesn't get refreshed data from servlet context attribute.
Can anyone please let me know what could be the problem?

Comment: Why in hell are you using an instance variable? Make the variable a local variable. An action is a singleton, used by many threads in parallel. It shouldn't have instance variables.

Comment: Saving data in the context is not a good idea, change it to a database and you will have all the data up to date.

Comment: This is a very old project and have been using servlet context  and instance variable everywhere. Its very hard to do any changes at this point of time. Just want to find out root cause and quick fix for now.